# Displaying same message for both save and submit after updating data into database in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi iam updating the form in php. I have two buttons like save and submit button. Need to display different message for save and submit button (now displaying same message for both.)

```
<?php include 'includes/db.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit_user']) || isset($_POST['save_users']) ){
    
    $formsubmitstatus = isset($_POST['submit_user'])?1:0;
    
    $firstname=$_POST['first_name'];
    $father_name=$_POST['father_name'];
    $user_gender=$_POST['user_gender'];
    $nationality=$_POST['nationality'];
    $dob=$_POST['dob']; 
    $place_of_practice=$_POST['place_of_practice'];
    
    $id= $_POST['users_id'];
    
        $ins_sql = "UPDATE users set first_name='$firstname',father_name='$father_name',user_gender='$user_gender',nationality='$nationality',dob='$dob',status='3', profile_submit_status='$formsubmitstatus',place_of_practice='$place_of_practice' WHERE users_id = $id";
        $run_sql = mysqli_query($conn,$ins_sql);
        $msg = 'Personal Details have been Submitted';    
        $msgclass = 'bg-success';
        //header("Location: edit.php");
    }else {
        $msg = 'Record Not Updated';      
        $msgclass = 'bg-danger';
    }
 ?>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="edituser.php?id=<?php echo $row['users_id'] ;?>" method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <?php if(isset($msg)) {?>
                                <div class="<?php echo $msgclass; ?>"  id="mydiv" style="padding:5px;"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <input  type='hidden' value='<?=$id;?>' name='users_id'>
                                <div class="form-group"> 
                                    <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">1. Name of the Candidate( As per Law Degree Certificate )</label> 
                                    <div class="col-sm-9"> 
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $oppointArr['first_name'];?>" name="first_name" id="first_name"  > 
                                    </div> 
                                </div>  
<div class="col-sm-offset-2">
                                    <?php if($oppointArr['profile_submit_status'] == 0){ ?>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="save_users" id="save_users">Save</button>   
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit_user" id="subject">Submit Application Details</button>       
                                    <?php } ?>                                      
                                     
                                    <!--<button type="cancel" class="btn btn-raised"><a href="http://dfstagingserver.com/enrolment/employee/edit.php">Cancel</a></button>-->
                                </div> 
                            </form>
```

Need to display different message for save button and Submit button.

Comment: Just change the $msg according to `isset($_POST['submit_user'])` or `isset($_POST['save_users'])`

Comment: @KenLee not getting where to change this

Comment: can anyone suggest how to fix this

Comment: What's your **exact** question about this? Why not distinguish between the two cases and change the message accordingly? Additionally, be warned that your query is widely open for SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the $msg according to ($_POST['submit_user']) or ($_POST['save_users'])

(1) change this line

```
  $msg = 'Personal Details have been Submitted';
```

to

```
if ($_POST['submit_user']) {  
$msg = 'Personal Details have been Submitted (submit button pressed)';  }

if ($_POST['save_users']) {  
$msg = 'Personal Details have been Submitted (save button pressed)';  }
```

(2) and please change the lines

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="save_users" id="save_users">Save</button>   
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit_user" id="subject">Submit Application Details</button>
```

to

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="save_users"  value="save_users" id="save_users">Save</button>   
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit_user"  value="submit_user"  id="subject">Submit Application Details</button>
```

Note: codes updated and tested in a real server of real DB

Comment: getting error as PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'isset' (T_ISSET), expecting '(' in edituser.php on line 58

Comment: getting same issue after updation as well

Comment: not displaying any message saved or submitted

Comment: Oh let me check again

Comment: Earlier it is displaying same message for save and submit but now it is not displaying anything

Comment: Codes updated and proven to be ok , you may see this http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/edituser18jan2021.php